# Laravel. I could not get the data from the post on the controller

Tags: ajax, laravel, post

Laravel 5. I'm totally new to Laravel. And fails to get javascript ajax data to controller.

There is a "master" file. It is "yield" file with ajax javascript. Where the ajax javascript is loaded the table file. The table top is "pagination" by pushing reloads only table. The rest of the page does not change.

**routes.php**

```
    Route::get('/', 'AddressController@tablePage');

    Route::post('addresses.table', 'AddressController@table');


// Route::post('addresses.table', function(){
//  return var_dump(Input::all());
// });
```

**AddressController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AddressController extends Controller {

    public function tablePage()
    {
        return view('addresses.page');
    }


    public function table()
    {
        return var_dump(Input::all());
        // $r = 0; //Input::get('r');
        // $f = '';//Input::get('f');
        // $rc = 5;//Input::get('rc');

        // $add = \App\Models\Address::table('work_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$f.'%', $rc ,$r);
        // $addRowCount = \App\Models\Address::tableRowCount('work_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$f.'%');

        // $data = [
        //  'addresses' => $add,
        //  'addRowCount' => $addRowCount, 
        //  'rc' => $rc, 
        //  'r' => $r
        // ];

        // return view('addresses.table', $data);
    }

}
```

**ajax javascript file**

```
// function runing when clicking on pagination
    function fnLoadTable(r)
    {
        $('#mainGifLoader').fadeIn('fast');

        if(typeof r == 'undefined')
            r = 1;

        var f = '';//$('#tFind').val();
        var rc = 5;//$('#pageTableRowCount').val(); 

        if(typeof rc == 'undefined')
            rc = 5;

        $.post(
            'addresses.table', 
            { r:r, f:f, rc:rc }, 
            function(result)
            {
                $('#idTable').html(result);
                $('#mainGifLoader').fadeOut('fast');
            }); 
    };
```

To use the ajax post had bent token.

From javascript data is sent. This can be seen when used comented route.

But AddressCountroller @ table, I can not get to these POST data.

**Where would be a mistake?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this according to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#named-routes):

in routes:

```
Route::post('addresses/table', [
    'as' => 'table', 'uses' => 'AddressController@table'
]);
```

in jquery:

```
     $.post(
        '/addresses/table', 
        { r:r, f:f, rc:rc }, 
        function(result)
        {
            $('#idTable').html(result);
            $('#mainGifLoader').fadeOut('fast');
        });
```

Comment: you are not supposed to use "." use "/" instead. @user3026906

Answer (score 0):

By default, except `GET` and `HEAD` request, laravel5 expects a csrf token along with the post data. unless you are sending the token in `$.ajaxSetup()`, then you have to include the token in the request. Otherwise, you'll get a 500 Internal server error with the message `Tokenmismatch exception`.

Modify your code on the following part:

```
 $.post(
        'addresses.table', 
        { r:r, f:f, rc:rc, _token:"{{csrf_token()}}" }, 
        function(result)
        {
            $('#idTable').html(result);
            $('#mainGifLoader').fadeOut('fast');
        });
```

you need to send an additional parameter "_token" alongwith other data.